# Javascript issue - On Page load all thre "tabs" show, when clicked it collapses like it should

Tags: javascript, twitter

On a page load of my website, the Twitter area shows all three portions of the "tabs". When I click say on the #HVC "tab" it loads correctly and then all three of the "tabs" look correctly.

Any ideas on why it's not loading properly on load?

Is there any easier way to do what I am trying to do without so many js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error when I load the page ([firebug](http://getfirebug.com/))

```
jQuery.timeago is undefined
[Break on this error] jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
```

I would investigate that.

Comment: Thanks much - any ideas what that means or how to go about hunting down a fix?

Is there any easier way to do what I am trying to do without so many js files?

Comment: This helped me fix a separate issue but not the current issue at hand.

Moved it to a separate question for clarification